How to prevent Safari from unloading off-screen elements in a React application?
I'm developing a React application and I've encountered an issue where Safari aggressively unloads elements that are off-screen, which causes problems with smooth scrolling and animations.
I am using the react-scroll-parallax library for animations. When this library is active, it takes too long for elements to become visible while scrolling. However, when I disable the library, the page usage becomes more convenient.
Are there any known solutions or best practices to prevent Safari from unloading off-screen elements? Specifically, I'm looking for ways to keep off-screen elements in memory or manage this behavior effectively.
Thank you!
